# kubectl cp command is encrypted or not like sftp

Tags: kubernetes, copy, sftp, kubectl, cp

Does anyone has any idea how can i check if kubectl cp commnd sends data in encrypted form or not.

Tried to take the dump using tcpdump while running "kubectl cp" command but could not find anything to prove "if it is encrypted or not"

Comment: kubectl keeps the data in encrypted form but what while transferring data using kubectl cp it is sent in ecrypted form or not.

Comment: Yes, all communication with the Kubernetes control plane is encrypted. That includes calls like `kubectl cp`.

Comment: @Botje can you please provide any link how can i prove it. As with the tcpdump output i can see all communication is encrypted but in official document "kubectl cp" copies data to remote node and tar it , but nowhere they have mentioned about encryption.

Comment: The kube-apiserver program only accepts https connections, there is no provision for unencrypted http.